# After adding firebase to my flutter app, ui is not showing

Tags: flutter, firebase

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_firebase_test/firebase_options.dart';

void main() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

when i remove two line of code it work fine.

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,);
```

Ui should be loaded as it is before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`:

```dart
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write the main method as asynchronous, and you run a Flutter app, the asynchronous method waits for the Firebase connection. As a result, your UI will be paused. To avoid this problem, you can write it like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  init();
}

void init() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
}
```

So try to avoid main method as as async and also not write await method in main method

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).